# Symfony 2: updating table schema not reflected in phpadmin

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have some beginners questions regarding Symfony 2 which I cannot get clear answers for from previous questions (perhaps because they are genuinely basic)

1. When you create a new symfony2 project from the command line and specific the database name and passwords, is this meant to automatically create the database (which you can see in phpmyadmin) or does one manually do this.
2. Following from this, if one creates a number of entities and then uses

   ```
    doctrine:schema:update
   ```

Should the specified tables be automatically created in the database you have specified in the projects "parameters.yml" file.

I have performed "doctrine:schema:update --force" which then gave me

```
 Updating database schema...
 Database schema updated successfully! "2" queries were executed
```

But no tables were created. So I tried again, to see what the message would be...

```
 unknown-ec:35:86:4d:41:5e:symfony simonalice$ php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
 Nothing to update - your database is already in sync with the current entity metadata.
 unknown-ec:35:86:4d:41:5e:symfony simonalice$
```

So clearly Doctrine thinks its in synch - but no tables in phpmyadmin.

Clearly complete beginners stuff....but I would be grateful for some steerage on this from a Symfony 2 veteran.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your questions:

1. No, creating a new Symfony project will not create your database (or the user connecting to it). You still need to do that and I would recommend you create a dedicated user for your application with suitable permissions. You'll need to use a database user with administrative privileges to do this. For security reasons, it's best **to not use your database administrator account** with your application. To instruct doctrine to create your database (once you have your db user and connection parameters set), you can run the `php app/console doctrine:database:create` console command.
2. Yes, running the `doctrine:schema:update` console command will generate your database entities, but it won't/can't create your database. You can also use the `--force` option to apply changes you've made since the last update. These updates will still be bound by any column constraints you've defined, so if for example you change an existing nullable column to `not null`, you'll get an error if records already exist with null values.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Many thanks for your comments Haig. The problem I am facing (I am going through a few tutorials on Symfony2) is that it appears in the tutorial, that when a new project is created from the command line, and all the parameters are specified, including the database name etc, the database is then created in MySQL. From your answer, this is not the case and certainly, when I create a new project, I have to create the database myself. What is really bugging me is that after I have created entities, if I 'doctrine:schema:update' nothing happens in phpmyadmin - there are no tables created....

Comment: .....the impression I am getting is that my project isn't 'communicating' with MySQL (as reflected in the lack of changes in phpmyadmin). Its created a block to my progress. If you have insights into why this maybe I would be really interested. Cheers

Comment: It's certainly possible that the application isn't communicating with the database. This can happen if your configuration parameters are wrong or if the server on which your database resides is rejecting connection attempts (eg: blocking requests on the port). Best way to diagnose this is to look at log files. Symfony has log files in the `app/logs` directory. Apache server log files on linux systems are typically located in `/var/log/httpd` and mysql log files are typically located in `/var/log/`. Start there or you'll just be groping in the dark.